# VBA script won't run. Getting Run Time Error 424 Object required

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a run time error when I try to run this. Can anyone solve this?

```
Sub recolor()
'Sub Color_Change

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:E16")

If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Intersect(Target, rng)
        Dim cellValue As String
        Dim rgbArray() As String
        cellValue = cell.Value
        rgbArray = Split(cellValue, ", ")
        If UBound(rgbArray) = 2 Then
            Dim red As Integer
            Dim green As Integer
            Dim blue As Integer
            red = CInt(rgbArray(0))
            green = CInt(rgbArray(1))
            blue = CInt(rgbArray(2))
            cell.Interior.Color = RGB(red, green, blue)
        End If
    Next cell
End If
End Sub
```

I am getting a Object required error

Comment: What is `Target` here?  You've not declared it, so is it a Global variable?

Comment: ...might help to explain how the code is triggered, and on what range it's supposed to operate.

Comment: Hi Tim,  the target are the cells. The contents of the cells have a RGB color code, such as "99, 190, 123" or "249, 124, 110".  I would like the cell to be the color that is listed in the cell. Does that help? Cells A1:E16 contain values in the format "###,###,###". I need this to be dynamic.

Comment: What cells exactly do you want to run this on?  All cells in A1:E16?  If Yes then what is Target for here?  If No then which cells should be processed?  There is no global `Target` range edfined for you in Excel VBA - typically `Target` shows up as a parameter in event procedures, where (eg) `Target` represents a range of cells being changed or selected.

Comment: What cells exactly do you want to run this on? Yes, I want to run this on cells A1:E16. If Yes then what is Target for here? I am not sure - I did not write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `Target` if you just want to process a fixed range:

```vb
Sub recolor()
    Dim cell As Range, arr
  
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E16").Cells 'or use a specific worksheet
        arr = Split(cell.Value, ",")
        If UBound(arr) = 2 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = _
              RGB(CLng(Trim(arr(0))), CLng(Trim(arr(1))), CLng(Trim(arr(2))))
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```